# CORS with apollo-server-express

Tags: node.js, cors, apollo

I am using apollo-server-express like this:

```
  // Express setup
  const app = express()
  app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 10000000, maxFiles: 10 }))
  app.use(cors())
```

Apollo is set up like this:

```
  // Apollo setup
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context,
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({
        httpServer: http.createServer(app),
        stopGracePeriodMillis: 10000,
      }),
    ],
    introspection: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  })
  await server.start()

  // Mount Apollo middleware
  server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false, path: '/' })
```

Relevant versions:

```
"apollo-server-core": "^3.10.2",
"apollo-server-express": "^3.4.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"graphql": "^16.0.1",
"graphql-upload": "^15.0.0",
```

Issue I am having is that uploading image and CORS (this is only happening remotely)

[image]

Description: Option request returns this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*
Date:
Thu, 22 Jun 2023 09:00:41 GMT
Vary:
Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Powered-By:
Express
```

Post request fails with 403

Note: Same POST request succeeds when called from Postman or Apollo Studio

This is text from console

```
Text: Access to fetch at 'https://graphql.xxxx-dev.xxxx/' from origin 'https://xxxx-dev.xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

createUploadLink.js:208     POST https://graphql.xxxx-dev.xxxx/ net::ERR_FAILED 403

ApolloError: Failed to fetch
```

From localhost all is working as expected and there is no CORS issue.
(I tried to increase maxFileSize and that did not work)

Are there any options to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: It's not the `OPTIONS` request fails, but `POST`.

Comment: Please read how to add CORS: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/cors/

Comment: Yes, OPTIONS is ok, but POST fails